# How to prevent Flexbox item from filling parent

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I have a simple DOM structure:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <div class='card'>
            <h1>HEADER<h1>
            <div>
               Some dynamic content
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body
```

styled such that a main tag consumes the height of the window, is set up to display as flex, and centers a card element.  But,  the card seems to want to take up the height of its parent (main) even though what I'd expect (and want) is the card to size it its content.  I'd prefer to not set an explicit height on the card.

Here is a JSfiddle that demonstrates the problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/hjeq78c4/2/

How do I prevent this card item from extending all the way to the bottom and only size to its content

Comment: Just add `align-items: flex-start` to the flex container.

Comment: Great, that was easy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Just what michael_b said
Adding `align-items: flex-start` to your main tag would solve the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/hjeq78c4/2/